# Install Ubuntu without using a USB or disc?

Tags: system-installation

I can't remember my Dell Inspiron admin password for entering Bios to set it up, so to boot Ubuntu from start up and I don't feel like tearing my laptop apart to take out the Bios battery just to reset it, so I was hoping that I could just download Ubuntu 12.04 directly to run along with my Windows 7.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Is there a way to get to the boot menu? Maybe F2 oder F12? -> Manual

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely possible.

This is how you do it (for safety do a backup before following the instructions, in case something go wrong);

First make sure you boot Windows, then download your iso if you haven't already. Afterwards download https://sourceforge.net/projects/partedmagic/files/partedmagic/Parted%20Magic%205.5/pmagic-5.5.iso.zip/download

and lastly http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Now, run the Unetbootin installer. Choose your Parted Magic iso and choose frugal install.

Install it to your windows partition (normally C:) when it tells you it's done you can reboot.

When you reboot into your unetbootin installation you should be able to choose to load Parted Magic entirely into RAM. This means that, once running, it will not actually be using the hard disk at all - leaving you free to resize the partitions.

Once Parted Magic has booted, select the gparted application. It's fairly easy to use. simply select your Windows partition, click edit, and shrink it by about 8Gb.

Make sure you leave the empty space to the right of the partition. Then click apply.

Unetbootin may prompt you to remove the installation. If not running the unetbootin installer again should remove it. (If neither happens then control panel and add/ remove programs on XP or Programs and features on vista/7 and remove it there).

Run the Unetbootin installer again and this time, select your Ubuntu iso to use for the frugal install. Reboot into this new installation. Once in Ubuntu, run gparted.

In the spare space create a new partition, and format it as ext4 (often you'll be told to create a swap partition; you can if you want; I don't normally; google will tell you more). Click the install icon on the desktop. When it gets to partitioning, click specify manually. Choose your new partition and pick use as: ext4, mount point: / Let the installer do its job. now you have a choice. Left like this the system will allow you to dual-boot (i.e. choose between Ubuntu and Windows when you switch on the pc).

Reinstall Parted Magic as we did in step 1. Reboot to parted magic (loading it to RAM again). Open up gparted, move the Ubuntu partition to the left, then grow it to the right. Do not try to grow it to the left. (This is the time to create your swap partition if you want one). Now reboot. You have now installed Ubuntu alongside Windows without even touching a disc or usb! :)

The source: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/171

Comment: Will this still work if the BIOS is locked and the OP does not know the password? how would he get past the BIOS to boot any OS or from any external disk?

Comment: Didn't he implicitly say he had alread Windows installed? It is my understanding he can't access the BIOS just to change the settings, but he can boot ('for entering Bios to set
it up').

Comment: I think you are correct, I was reading Bios password and was thinking admin password, i.e. not able to get past the BIOS to boot....He does not say that he cannot boot into Windows now that I reread it with your comment in mind....there was a question very similar to this a few days ago but the OP could not boot, so I guess that I took this question to mean that as well.  I was not challenging your answer btw, just asking  for clarification as I was confused, thought you new something I didn't, guess you just read it better than I....

Comment: @TrailRider don't worry, we human aren't perfect :) this is the spirit of the community, we help and learn from each other. Just make sure you read the question at least 2 times :P

Comment: @vasa1 sorry, I thought that putting effort and changing the instruction for a specific os would make it eligible to be original :/ I write now from my smartphone. A comment would suffice ;) Anyway I added the source at the end, let me know if it's good.